# Created shapefile layer from selected feature, nothing displaying on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I selected a feature (watershed) from layer, created a shapefile layer from it, I bring it into QGIS and nothing displays as if there is no data attached to it? Any ideas?

[image: enter code here]

Comment: what happens if you clear the selection?

Comment: What software and methodology did you use to create the watershed shapefile?  Knowing that would help provide an answer.

Comment: If you right-click on the newly created shapefile in the Layers panel and select 'Open Attribute Table' does it show any features there? What happens if you right-click on it and select 'Zoom to Layer' - is it located where you expected?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to play a bit with the symbology of the watershed-layer in QGIS? I sometimes find it a bit tricky to make layers appear properly...